# C# keyboard event handler rectangle

Tags: c#, events, drawing

I am new to C# and try to make an keyboard event. It should display when the keys W, A, S or D are pressed. First my plan was to show some pictureBox and just change the picture if the right keys are pressed.

But then I searched the internet an found something similar in Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/sample-apps/KeyboardExample.zip
and it looks like this:
[image]

As I can understand the code is drawing a rectangle with some letter in it. I looked the msdn and found a example for drawing a rectangle:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sx8yykw8(v=vs.110).aspx

Unfortunately I stucking in the drawing. Normally I use the toolbox to add things to the form. Then I double-click it and write my code inside the braces. But there is no "Rectangle" in the toolbox, so I am not sure how to add it.

This is my code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Stay always on top
        this.TopMost = true;
        //Does not work. Removes border but you can't move the window after this
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Can I delete this?            
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar >= 65 && e.KeyChar <= 122)
        {
            switch (e.KeyChar)
            {
                //If pressed w or W
                case (char)119:
                case (char)87:
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
                    break;
                //If pressed a or A
                case (char)97:
                case (char)65:
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
                    break;
                //If pressed s or S
                case (char)83:
                case (char)115:
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
                    break;
                //If pressed d or D
                case (char)100:
                case (char)68:
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
                    break;
                //Other keys
                default:
                    lblMessage.Text = "Key not supported";
                    //does not work
                    //timer1_Tick();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Hide();
    }
}
```

And here is how my Form looks now:

[image]

Other things I am stucking at the moment:

- How I can call the timer from the Form1_KeyPress to hide the lblMessage after some seconds?
- Remove border without losing the ability to move the window (like with `this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;` for example)

EDIT: I changed the code to the newest working state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Windows desktop programming!

You have two choices here; you can either:

1. Add components to the WASD form using the Design View (and since you have the W, A, S, D boxes there it looks like you have already added them in) and in your Form1_KeyPress() handler, just update the properties of the boxes. This can be as simple as the following, just make sure to change it to the correct component name:

   ```
   //If pressed w or W
   case (char)119:
   case (char)87:
           Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
           button1.BackColor = Color.Red;//Highlight W
           button2.BackColor = Color.Empty;//Ignore A
           button3.BackColor = Color.Empty;//Ignore S
           button3.BackColor = Color.Empty;//Ignore D
           break;
   ```
2. Override the form's OnDraw() handler and paint the boxes directly on the screen. This is harder but gives you a lot more power.

Turning off the label is easy. In your Form1_Load() handler make sure to set the timer1's timeout property:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 5000;//In ms = thousandths-of-a-second
}
```

Turn the timer on in the Form1_KeyPress() handler:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    lblMessage.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Do your work and turn off the timer in the timer1_Tick() handler:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Enabled = false;
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: I tried to change the color with `pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;` but it doesn't work. I think it is because it is just a picture I imported with a picturebox?

Comment: Also how is the 2nd option working? What do you mean with more power? Will it be better coded than with a picture?

Comment: Thanks for the help with the timer. Now it looks easy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I quickly put together:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WASD_Keyboard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        private bool wPressed = false;
        private bool aPressed = false;
        private bool sPressed = false;
        private bool dPressed = false;
        private Timer timer = new Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Stay always on top
            this.TopMost = true;
            //Does not work. Removes border but you can't move the window after this
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            timer.Interval = 3000;
            //this is an event binding
            timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Dock the PictureBox to the form and set its background to white.
            pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            pictureBox1.Paint += DrawRectangleRectangle;
            // Add the PictureBox control to the Form.
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // reversed logic to stop nesting
            if (e.KeyChar < 65 || e.KeyChar > 122) return;

            wPressed = false;
            aPressed = false;
            sPressed = false;
            dPressed = false;
            //this should really be multiple if statement so it can do more than one key
            //If pressed w or W
            if (e.KeyChar == (char) 119 || e.KeyChar == (char) 87) {
                wPressed = true;
                Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
            }

            //If pressed a or A
            if (e.KeyChar == (char) 97 || e.KeyChar == (char) 65) {
                aPressed = true;
                Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
            }

            //If pressed s or S
            if (e.KeyChar == (char) 83 || e.KeyChar == (char) 115) {
                sPressed = true;
                Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
            }

            //If pressed d or D
            if (e.KeyChar == (char) 100 || e.KeyChar == (char) 68) {
                dPressed = true;
                Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
            }

            if (!wPressed && !aPressed && !sPressed && !dPressed) {
                //Something goes wrong
                lblMessage.Text = "Key not supported";
                return;
            }

            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            // in older .net if you didn't do both you ran into multiple issues
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
        }

        public void DrawRectangleRectangle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawRectangle(e, new Point(40, 10), new Size(20, 20), 'W', wPressed ? Color.Red : Color.White);
            DrawRectangle(e, new Point(10, 40), new Size(20, 20), 'A', aPressed ? Color.Red : Color.White);
            DrawRectangle(e, new Point(40, 40), new Size(20, 20), 'S', sPressed ? Color.Red : Color.White);
            DrawRectangle(e, new Point(70, 40), new Size(20, 20), 'D', dPressed ? Color.Red : Color.White);
        }

        public void DrawRectangle(PaintEventArgs e, Point p, Size s, char letter, Color c)
        {
            // Create pen.
            var blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
            var brush = new SolidBrush(c);
            // Create rectangle.
            var rect = new Rectangle(p, s);

            // Draw rectangle to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(letter.ToString(), new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 12), Brushes.Blue, rect);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wPressed = false;
            aPressed = false;
            sPressed = false;
            dPressed = false;

            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Stop();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:*** This is highly async but doesn't use any locking...

Comment: What is this `timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;` doing? I only know `+=` means `var = var + a;`

Comment: Isn't `timer.Enabled = false;` and `timer.Stop();` the same doing?

Comment: Why is there a return in `if (e.KeyChar < 65 || e.KeyChar > 122) return;` ? For reasons or a typo?

Comment: Oh I understand you changed to AND to OR this is really a interesting solution.

Comment: Works great! I only had to change the word `timer` on line 81 and 82 to `timer1`. Thank you for this big help.

Comment: @user3772108 updated to have comments.  On line 81 it can be `timer` or `timer1` these are simply variable names